# Can I use conditional branching in xml email templates

Tags: xml, email-templates

I want to have generalised email templates. Currently I have multiple email templates with some part of the subject and body being changed. I would like to club them together with some conditional branching like,

```
<email>
   <sub>
      if(condition)
           sub1
      else
           sub2
    </sub>
    <body>
        some text
        if(condition)
             text...
        else
             text...

        body continued...
    </body>
</email>
```

Can I do this in any way?

Comment: Have you looked at [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task it is a good idea to use a template engine. There exist template engines for plain text (like [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)) which you can use for generating XML too. There are also specialized template engines for XML, like XSLT (with various implementions for nearly every programming environment) or [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) (with a special XML mode).

Look at the [Wikipedia template engine page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) for a comparison table.